# Turn an old Samsung Galaxy S6 into a GameBoy/eBook reader

Tags: adb, samsung, bloatware, disable-app

I have a Galaxy Tab S6 (I know, old...) and I would like to turn it into something that, once turned on, will do two things:

- GameBoy (via an emulator)
- Ebook (via the Kindle reader)

I want to make dead sure nothing else is usable/visible. I am talking about Chrome, settings, and anything. When I want to install new GameBoy games, I will upload them to the tablet via ADB.

I enabled developers mode on the tablet, and enabled USB debugging. I got onto the shell (I am OK with the Unix command line) and ran `pm list packages` and got this:

```
package:com.monotype.android.font.rosemary
package:com.sec.android.app.DataCreate
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.samsungapps
package:com.google.android.youtube
package:com.sec.android.app.chromecustomizations
package:com.android.providers.telephony
package:com.sec.android.app.parser
package:com.android.providers.calendar
package:com.osp.app.signin
package:com.samsung.clipboardsaveservice
package:com.android.providers.media
package:com.google.android.onetimeinitializer
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.digitalclock
package:com.android.wallpapercropper
package:com.sec.factory.camera
package:org.simalliance.openmobileapi.service
package:com.sec.usbsettings
package:com.android.documentsui
package:com.android.externalstorage
package:com.sec.factory
package:com.android.htmlviewer
package:com.android.mms.service
package:com.sec.android.wallpapercropper2
package:com.android.providers.downloads
package:com.android.browser.provider
package:com.hancom.androidpc.appwidget
package:com.sec.android.app.FlashBarService
package:com.sec.android.Kies
package:com.samsung.android.email.sync
package:com.monotype.android.font.foundation
package:com.samsung.android.email.provider
package:com.samsung.android.MtpApplication
package:com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring
package:com.sec.android.app.samsungapps
package:com.sec.android.emergencymode.service
package:com.google.android.configupdater
package:com.sec.android.app.wlantest
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.SPlannerAppWidget
package:com.sec.android.app.billing
package:com.android.defcontainer
package:com.sec.android.daemonapp
package:com.android.vending
package:com.android.pacprocessor
package:com.samsung.android.email.ui
package:com.sec.android.app.popupuireceiver
package:com.samsung.android.SettingsReceiver
package:com.sec.android.app.soundalive
package:com.sec.android.providers.security
package:com.sec.android.provider.badge
package:com.android.certinstaller
package:com.samsung.android.securitylogagent
package:com.google.android.marvin.talkback
package:com.samsung.android.app.assistantmenu
package:com.samsung.android.email.composer
package:com.samsung.SMT
package:android
package:com.android.contacts
package:com.android.backupconfirm
package:com.samsung.klmsagent
package:com.samsung.android.app.memo
package:com.sec.android.app.SecSetupWizard
package:com.sprd.thermal
package:com.google.android.gm
package:com.samsung.android.scloud.auth
package:com.samsung.android.scloud.sync
package:com.sec.android.app.hwmoduletest
package:com.sec.bcservice
package:com.android.calendar
package:com.sec.modem.settings
package:com.sec.android.app.sysscope
package:com.sec.android.app.wallpaperchooser
package:com.sec.android.app.servicemodeapp
package:com.sec.android.preloadinstaller
package:com.google.android.setupwizard
package:com.sec.android.gallery3d
package:com.android.providers.settings
package:com.android.sharedstoragebackup
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.dualclockdigital
package:com.samsung.android.app.colorblind
package:com.hancom.office.hshow.viewer.hshow_viewer_apk
package:com.google.android.music
package:com.sec.android.pagebuddynotisvc
package:com.android.printspooler
package:com.android.dreams.basic
package:com.sec.android.app.music
package:com.android.incallui
package:com.android.inputdevices
package:com.sec.android.Preconfig
package:com.hancom.androidpc.hanupdater
package:com.google.android.apps.docs
package:com.google.android.apps.maps
package:com.sec.enterprise.mdm.vpn
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.at.hero.accuweather
package:com.sec.android.inputmethod
package:com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
package:com.sec.android.app.clockpackage
package:com.sec.android.RilServiceModeApp
package:com.google.android.webview
package:com.sec.android.app.simsettingmgr
package:com.android.server.telecom
package:com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts
package:com.android.keychain
package:com.android.chrome
package:com.samsung.android.asksmanager
package:com.samsung.android.sm
package:com.google.android.gms
package:com.google.android.gsf
package:com.google.android.tts
package:com.google.android.partnersetup
package:com.sec.android.diagmonagent
package:com.android.packageinstaller
package:com.google.android.videos
package:com.sec.spp.push
package:com.sec.android.app.myfiles
package:com.android.proxyhandler
package:com.samsung.android.allshare.service.fileshare
package:com.sec.android.app.launcher
package:com.hancom.office.hcell.viewer.hcell_viewer_apk
package:com.sec.android.app.sns3
package:com.google.android.feedback
package:com.google.android.apps.photos
package:com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar
package:com.android.managedprovisioning
package:com.sec.android.providers.tasks
package:com.monotype.android.font.chococooky
package:com.android.dreams.phototable
package:com.samsung.safetyinformation
package:com.sec.android.app.ringtoneBR
package:com.android.providers.partnerbookmarks
package:com.google.android.gsf.login
package:com.cleanmaster.sdk
package:com.samsung.android.app.accesscontrol
package:com.android.wallpaper.livepicker
package:com.sec.enterprise.mdm.services.simpin
package:com.samsung.android.app.FileShareClient
package:com.hancom.androidpc.viewer.launcher
package:com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator
package:com.sec.android.soagent
package:com.samsung.android.scloud.backup
package:com.samsung.android.fmm
package:com.samsung.android.mdm
package:com.sec.phone
package:com.google.android.backuptransport
package:com.sec.android.app.kidshome
package:com.visionobjects.resourcemanager
package:com.samsung.android.smcore
package:com.android.settings
package:com.sec.android.app.bluetoothtest
package:com.sec.android.emergencylauncher
package:com.sec.hearingadjust
package:com.sec.android.splitsound
package:com.wssnps
package:com.policydm
package:com.hancom.androidpc.launcher.shared
package:com.samsung.android.app.FileShareServer
package:com.sec.android.app.snsimagecache
package:com.android.vpndialogs
package:com.google.android.talk
package:com.android.phone
package:com.android.shell
package:com.sec.tcpdumpservice
package:com.android.providers.userdictionary
package:com.sec.enterprise.knox.cloudmdm.smdms
package:com.wssyncmldm
package:com.android.location.fused
package:com.android.systemui
package:com.monotype.android.font.cooljazz
package:com.sec.android.provider.logsprovider
package:com.samsung.aasaservice
package:com.sec.android.app.fm
package:com.sec.android.app.mt
package:com.hancom.office.hword.viewer.hword_apk
package:com.sec.android.provider.emergencymode
package:com.sec.android.app.camera
package:com.android.bluetooth
package:com.google.android.androidforwork
package:com.android.providers.contacts
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.webmanual
package:com.samsung.sec.android.application.csc
package:com.android.captiveportallogin
package:com.samsung.android.video
package:com.samsung.android.email.widget
package:com.samsung.location
shell@gtexswifi:/ $ pm list packages                                           
package:com.monotype.android.font.rosemary
package:com.sec.android.app.DataCreate
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.samsungapps
package:com.google.android.youtube
package:com.sec.android.app.chromecustomizations
package:com.android.providers.telephony
package:com.sec.android.app.parser
package:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
package:com.android.providers.calendar
package:com.osp.app.signin
package:com.samsung.clipboardsaveservice
package:com.android.providers.media
package:com.google.android.onetimeinitializer
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.digitalclock
package:com.android.wallpapercropper
package:com.sec.factory.camera
package:org.simalliance.openmobileapi.service
package:com.sec.usbsettings
package:com.android.documentsui
package:com.android.externalstorage
package:com.sec.factory
package:com.android.htmlviewer
package:com.android.mms.service
package:com.sec.android.wallpapercropper2
package:com.android.providers.downloads
package:com.android.browser.provider
package:com.hancom.androidpc.appwidget
package:com.sec.android.app.FlashBarService
package:com.sec.android.Kies
package:com.samsung.android.email.sync
package:com.monotype.android.font.foundation
package:com.samsung.android.email.provider
package:com.samsung.android.MtpApplication
package:com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring
package:com.sec.android.app.samsungapps
package:com.sec.android.emergencymode.service
package:com.google.android.configupdater
package:com.sec.android.app.wlantest
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.SPlannerAppWidget
package:com.sec.android.app.billing
package:com.android.defcontainer
package:com.sec.android.daemonapp
package:com.android.vending
package:com.android.pacprocessor
package:com.samsung.android.email.ui
package:com.sec.android.app.popupuireceiver
package:com.samsung.android.SettingsReceiver
package:com.sec.android.app.soundalive
package:com.sec.android.providers.security
package:com.sec.android.provider.badge
package:com.android.certinstaller
package:com.samsung.android.securitylogagent
package:com.google.android.marvin.talkback
package:com.samsung.android.app.assistantmenu
package:com.samsung.android.email.composer
package:com.samsung.SMT
package:android
package:com.android.contacts
package:com.android.backupconfirm
package:com.samsung.klmsagent
package:com.samsung.android.app.memo
package:com.sec.android.app.SecSetupWizard
package:com.sprd.thermal
package:com.google.android.gm
package:com.samsung.android.scloud.auth
package:com.samsung.android.scloud.sync
package:com.sec.android.app.hwmoduletest
package:com.sec.bcservice
package:com.android.calendar
package:com.sec.modem.settings
package:com.sec.android.app.sysscope
package:com.sec.android.app.wallpaperchooser
package:com.sec.android.app.servicemodeapp
package:com.sec.android.preloadinstaller
package:com.google.android.setupwizard
package:com.sec.android.gallery3d
package:com.android.providers.settings
package:com.android.sharedstoragebackup
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.dualclockdigital
package:com.samsung.android.app.colorblind
package:com.hancom.office.hshow.viewer.hshow_viewer_apk
package:com.google.android.music
package:com.sec.android.pagebuddynotisvc
package:com.android.printspooler
package:com.android.dreams.basic
package:com.sec.android.app.music
package:com.android.incallui
package:com.android.inputdevices
package:com.sec.android.Preconfig
package:com.hancom.androidpc.hanupdater
package:com.google.android.apps.docs
package:com.google.android.apps.maps
package:com.sec.enterprise.mdm.vpn
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.at.hero.accuweather
package:com.sec.android.inputmethod
package:com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
package:com.sec.android.app.clockpackage
package:com.sec.android.RilServiceModeApp
package:com.google.android.webview
package:com.sec.android.app.simsettingmgr
package:com.android.server.telecom
package:com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts
package:com.android.keychain
package:com.android.chrome
package:com.samsung.android.asksmanager
package:com.samsung.android.sm
package:com.google.android.gsf
package:com.google.android.tts
package:com.google.android.partnersetup
package:com.sec.android.diagmonagent
package:com.android.packageinstaller
package:com.google.android.videos
package:com.sec.spp.push
package:com.sec.android.app.myfiles
package:com.android.proxyhandler
package:com.samsung.android.allshare.service.fileshare
package:com.sec.android.app.launcher
package:com.hancom.office.hcell.viewer.hcell_viewer_apk
package:com.sec.android.app.sns3
package:com.google.android.feedback
package:com.google.android.apps.photos
package:com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar
package:com.android.managedprovisioning
package:com.sec.android.providers.tasks
package:com.monotype.android.font.chococooky
package:com.android.dreams.phototable
package:com.samsung.safetyinformation
package:com.sec.android.app.ringtoneBR
package:com.android.providers.partnerbookmarks
package:com.google.android.gsf.login
package:com.cleanmaster.sdk
package:com.samsung.android.app.accesscontrol
package:com.android.wallpaper.livepicker
package:com.sec.enterprise.mdm.services.simpin
package:com.samsung.android.app.FileShareClient
package:com.hancom.androidpc.viewer.launcher
package:com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator
package:com.sec.android.soagent
package:com.samsung.android.scloud.backup
package:com.samsung.android.fmm
package:com.samsung.android.mdm
package:com.sec.phone
package:com.google.android.backuptransport
package:com.sec.android.app.kidshome
package:com.visionobjects.resourcemanager
package:com.samsung.android.smcore
package:com.android.settings
package:com.sec.android.app.bluetoothtest
package:com.sec.android.emergencylauncher
package:com.sec.hearingadjust
package:com.sec.android.splitsound
package:com.wssnps
package:com.policydm
package:com.hancom.androidpc.launcher.shared
package:com.samsung.android.app.FileShareServer
package:com.sec.android.app.snsimagecache
package:com.android.vpndialogs
package:com.google.android.talk
package:com.android.phone
package:com.android.shell
package:com.sec.tcpdumpservice
package:com.android.providers.userdictionary
package:com.sec.enterprise.knox.cloudmdm.smdms
package:com.wssyncmldm
package:com.android.location.fused
package:com.android.systemui
package:com.monotype.android.font.cooljazz
package:com.sec.android.provider.logsprovider
package:com.samsung.aasaservice
package:com.sec.android.app.fm
package:com.sec.android.app.mt
package:com.hancom.office.hword.viewer.hword_apk
package:com.sec.android.provider.emergencymode
package:com.sec.android.app.camera
package:com.android.bluetooth
package:com.google.android.androidforwork
package:com.android.providers.contacts
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.webmanual
package:com.samsung.sec.android.application.csc
package:com.android.captiveportallogin
package:com.samsung.android.video
package:com.samsung.android.email.widget
package:com.samsung.location
```

I am not managing to disable Chrome:

```
pm disable com.android.chrome                            
Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid=11728, uid=2000, package uid=10065
```

Two questions:

- How do I disable packages? Do I need "root" permissions on the tablet?
- If/when I do become root, which ones shall I delete?

Comment: I would be more specific about the version of Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 to include model year/OS version as Samsung tends to reuse names/use similar names in various products, i.e. the Galaxy S6 (phone) is different from the Galaxy Tab S6 (tablet).